# Stochastic integral of local martingales is an extension

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I'm trying to prove that the stochastic integral defined for the set of square integrable local martingales is really an extension of ordinary stochastic integral. Define

$\mathcal{H}=\{(H_t)_{0\leq t\leq T}:H_t\,\, \text{adapted to}\,\,\mathcal{F}_t, E(\int_0^TH_s^2ds)<\infty\}$.
And denote the stochastic integral by $J(H)_t$ for $H\in\mathcal{H}$.

Now $\tilde{\mathcal{H}}=\{(H_t)_{0\leq t\leq T}:H_t\,\, \text{adapted to}\,\,\mathcal{F}_t, \int_0^TH_s^2ds<\infty\,\,a.s.\}$.

Then my book says that there exists a unique linear map $\tilde{J}$ from $\tilde{\mathcal{H}}$ to the vector space of continuous processes defined on $[0,T]$ such that:

1. If $H$ is a simple process $\tilde{J}(H)_t=J(H)_t$ for all $t\in[0,T]$ and $P$-a.s.
2. If $(H_n)\subset \tilde{\mathcal{H}}$ such that $\int_0^T(H_s^n)^2ds$ converges to 0 in probability, then $\sup_{0\leq t\leq T}|\tilde{J}(H^n)(t)|$ converges to 0 in probability.

I want to show that for $H\in\mathcal H$, $\tilde{J}(H)_t=J(H)_t$ almost surely so that $\tilde{J}$ is really an extension. I tried to solve this by choosing the approximating simple process $H^n\in \mathcal{H}$, but I'm stuck in applying the second property of $\tilde{J}$.

Comment: Do you know that for any $H \in \mathcal{H}$ there exists a sequence of simple processes $(H^n)_n$ such that $\mathbb{E}(\int_0^T (H_s-H_s^n)^2 \, ds) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$?